Probability of having even number of heads if $n-1$ (out of $n$) coins are fair and the remaining one lands on heads with probability $p$.
Suppose there are $n$ coins out of which the first $n-1$ coins are fair and the last one lands on head with probability $p \in [0,1]$. What is the probability of having even number of heads?
Probability of getting even number of heads when the fair coins are tossed is $1/2$. Accounting for all the tosses, we have $$\mathbb{P}(\text{even Heads}) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \cdot (p) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) (1-p) = \frac{1}{2}$$
Is my solution correct?

Note:  in your question, the case $n=1$ is problematic.  You need at least one fair coin, as the duplicate says.

@lulu Yes, we can assume $n$ to be sufficiently large. Can you please tell me the intuition behind $P = 1/2$?

Intuition:  Take one fair coin out and toss the rest.  They come up $H$ or $T$ with whatever probability.  However many Heads you get there, the fair one will make the total even with probability $\frac 12$.

@lulu Fantastic. Thank you!
